# Python inner parenthetic string parsing

Tags: python, string, parsing, parentheses

Alright, 
Currently, if given a string like such:

```
A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,(F:0.6,G:0.7)H:0.8
```

I am using this:

```
child = Pstring[Pstring.find('(')+1:Pstring.find(')')]
```

To iterate through the string, and print out the inner parenthesis, and assign it to the variable 'child'

Now, my question is, how can I do the same for:

```
W:1.0,X:1.1(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,(F:0.6,G:0.7)H:0.8)Y:0.9
```

Which just simply contains an outside parenthesis to show that everything(except W and X) are children of Y

I currently get an output of 'child' as:

```
A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4
```

Whereas what I want the code to do is to first parse through the outside parenthesis, and grab the inner ones first, then work on the outside last.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the contents of the inner parentheses, you can use `re.findall()` with the following regular expression:

```
\(([^()]*)\)
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'W:1.0,X:1.1(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,(F:0.6,G:0.7)H:0.8)Y:0.9'
>>> re.findall(r'\(([^()]*)\)', s)
['C:0.3,D:0.4', 'F:0.6,G:0.7']
```

Explanation:

```
\(        # literal '('
(         # start capturing group
  [^()]*    # any characters except '(' and ')', any number
)         # end capturing group
\)        # literal ')'
```

`re.findall()` returns the contents of the capturing group for each match.

Comment: hmm, i am trying to keep the output as a string, and not as a list, as i need to further split and cut it up in the rest of my program

Comment: Was there a .find function that searched from the back of a string?

Comment: @Sean The result here is a list of strings, and you said you want to iterate through the string, so you can just iterate over the list to get each matching portion as a string.  If this isn't what you need, edit your question to provide what you expect the output to be.